# How to escape a backslash that is already escaping a single quote in php?

Tags: php, variables, escaping

So I have a script that creates a script that can then create another script. See below, I have written (how do I escape this) where I'm not sure what to do.

```
fwrite($file, ' 

                fwrite($file, \'

                                 fwrite($file, (how do i escape this)\' (how do i escape this)\'

\'
');
fclose;
```

I really hope that makes sense to someone!

Comment: Te escape everything *(which is reserved)*, use a backslash before it. So, to escape backslash *(which is one of those reserved symbols)*, use a backslash before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape a backslash add another one:

```
echo " Escape \\";
```

Comment: This doesn't escape the following single quote, so this can't be done:   <?php fwrite($file, ' fwrite($file, \' $var = $_GET[\\'var\\']; \')') ;?>