# How to escape a backlash and single quote at the same time

Tags: php, escaping

I thought this piece of code should work due to the previous question I asked about this(link below):

```
<?php fwrite($file, ' fwrite($file, \' $var = $_GET[\\'var\\']; \')') ;?>
```

This is giving me an error: Unexpected "var" on line blahblahblah...

Any ideas?

Link to previous question:
[How to escape a backslash that is already escaping a single quote in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879708/how-to-escape-a-backslash-that-is-already-escaping-a-single-quote-in-php)

Comment: One for the backlash and one for the quote. `$a = ' fwrite($file, \' $var = $_GET[\\\'var\\\']; \')';`. Output: `fwrite($file, ' $var = $_GET[\'var\']; ')`

Comment: lol thanks, now I have to go back over 5000 lines of code! yay!

Comment: Maybe it's better to change some `'` to `"` instead of doing this terrible codes?

Comment: That would interfere with a lot of my other existing code.. this is the best way to generate a script that generates another script that generates html files with variables..

Comment: Following @u_mulder's comment, in case using `"` in the whole string (and you don't want to use the actual value of the variables, but the string itself), it would look something like this (note that you need to escape `$` too): `$b = " fwrite(\$file, ' \$var = \$_GET[\\'var\\']; ')";`. Output: `fwrite($file, ' $var = $_GET[\'var\']; ')`

Comment: I feel my way is a lot less confusing for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need one more backslash:

```
$_GET[\\\'var\\\']
```

One backslash is for escaping the single quote while the other for escaping the backslash.